# Find the fixed point of $\cos(x)$ (equivalently of $\cos(\cos(x))$) restricted to $[0,\frac \pi 2]$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, fixed-point-theorems

I've proved that $\cos(\cos(x))$ restricted to $[0,\frac  \pi 2]$ is a contraction, which imply by Banach's fixed point theorem that it has a unique fixed point on this interval.

I've also proved that $\cos(x)$ must also have a unique fixed point on this interval, and that it must be the same as the one for $\cos(\cos(x))$.

But, how can I find this fixed point explicitly ?

Comment: Remember the proof of the Banach fixed point theorem?

Comment: you might find this question of peripheral interest in connection with the cosine fixed point http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622088/conjecture-a-supremum-property-of-the-cosine-fixed-point?rq=1

Comment: Well, there's the method of the proof of the theorem...pick any starting point in your interval, and iterate the function on that point.    That sequence will converge to your fixed point

Comment: @Alan what happens if you try that? Try pressing cos repeatedly on a calculator, e.g.

Comment: Are you referring to the [Dottie number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DottieNumber.html), whose decimal expansion can be found [here](http://oeis.org/A003957) ?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098065/number-of-iterations-to-reach-cosines-fixed-point) might be of interest...

Comment: So this number whatever it is, is not a "easy to find" number ? It might not be rational ?

Comment: @user111854: as explained in the linked Wikipedia entry, it is a trascendental number as a consequence of the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem.