# Proving $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\alpha$ $a_1=\frac\pi4, a_n = \cos(a_{n-1})$

Tags: calculus, fixed-point-theorems, cauchy-sequences

> Let $a_1=\frac\pi4, a_n = \cos(a_{n-1})$
>
> Prove $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\alpha$.
>
> Where $\alpha$ is the solution for $\cos x=x$.
>
> Hint: check that $(a_n)$ is a cauchy sequence and use Lagrange's theorem.

Well I tried to show that it's a cauchy sequence: $|a_m-a_n|<\epsilon , \ \forall m,n$ but I just don't see how it's done with a trig recursion sequence...

Comment: This is a recent duplicate which I'm failing to find. **Edit:** It's not a duplicate after all, but it is the same problem. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/626455/proof-that-the-solution-to-cosx-x-is-the-limit-of-a-recursive-sequence).

Comment: you should have made the question a little better.. may be you write $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\alpha$ and in the next line you write "where $\alpha$ is solution of $\cos x =x$"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$
\cos(x):\left[\frac1{\sqrt2},\frac\pi4\right]\mapsto\left[\frac1{\sqrt2},\frac\pi4\right]
$$
and on $\left[\frac1{\sqrt2},\frac\pi4\right]$,
$$
\left|\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\cos(x)\right|=|\sin(x)|\le\frac1{\sqrt2}\lt1
$$
Thus, the [Mean Value Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) ensures that $\cos(x)$ is a contraction mapping on $\left[\frac1{\sqrt2},\cos\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)\right]$. The [Contraction Mapping Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping) says that $\cos(x)$ has a unique fixed point in $\left[\frac1{\sqrt2},\cos\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)\right]$. Furthermore, for $n\ge3$,
$$
\left|a_n-a_{n-1}\right|\le\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)^{n-3}\left|a_3-a_2\right|
$$
Thus, $a_n$ is a Cauchy sequence. The point to which it converges must be the unique fixed point where $\cos(x)=x$.

Comment: Without using the contraction mapping theorem, how can you conclude that: $$ \left|a_n-a_{n-1}\right|\le\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)^{n-3}\left|a_3-a_2\right| $$ ?

Comment: @GinKin: That is gotten using the Mean Value Theorem: since $|\sin(x)|\le\frac1{\sqrt2}$ on $\left[\frac1{\sqrt2},\frac\pi4\right]$, we have that, for some $\alpha_{n-1}$ between $a_{n-1}$ and $a_{n-2}$,
$$
\begin{align}
\left|a_n-a_{n-1}\right|
&=\left|\cos(a_{n-1})-\cos(a_{n-2})\right|\\
&=\left|\sin(\alpha_{n-1})(a_{n-1}-a_{n-2})\right|\\
&\le\frac1{\sqrt2}\left|a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}\right|
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Hints: exists $\;c\;$ between $\;a_n\;,\;a_m\;$ s.t.

$$|a_n-a_m|=|\cos(a_{n-1})-\cos(a_{m-1})|\stackrel{\text{MVT}}= |(\cos c)'||a_{n-1}-a_{m-1}|=q|a_{n-1}-a_{m-1}|$$

since $\;|(\cos(c))'|=|\sin(c)|\;$ cannot be $\;1\;$ (why?) , and now

$$|a_n-a_{n-1}|\le q|a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}|\le\ldots\le q^{n-1}|a_1-a_0|$$

Comment: It cannot be 1 because $c\in[\frac\pi 4 , \frac1{\sqrt2}]$ but why it becomes a constant... Why is it a telescopic sequence ?

Comment: **What** becomes constant? You know $\;\sin c=q<1\;$ for *any* possible $\;c\in\left[\frac\pi4\,,\,\frac1{\sqrt2}\right]\;$ , andthat's all that matters.

Comment: @DonAntonio, why is $c \in \left[ {\pi \over 4},{1 \over \sqrt 2} \right]$?

Comment: @DonAntonio, Why is the MVT make it $\le$? shouldn't it be an equality?

Comment: @AnnieOK, this is prehistory! Anyway, I can't remember what I was thinking of when I answered this, but you're right: under that MVT thing there must be an equality sign though this doesn't matter that much. Now, $$\frac1{\sqrt2}\le\cos\frac\pi4=\frac1{\sqrt2}<\frac\pi4$$ , so iterating cosine on these values leave us all the time between $\;\frac1{\sqrt2}\;$ and $\;\frac\pi4\;$ (remember: on $\;[0,\pi/2]\;,\;\;\cos x$  is motone *descending*)

Answer (score 1):

Look over the Banach Fixed Point Theorem. Its practically the same deal.

Hint: Show with MVT that:
$$ | \cos(a_{n}) - \cos(a_{n-1})| <= q^n|a_1 - a_0|$$
Where $q$ is a constant so $ 0 < q < 1 $. 
Use that in the Cauchy proof.

Comment: It's *exactly* the same proof as the BFPT's though I doubt it whether it'd be allowed to use that theorem in Calculus I. Yet the MVT allows to prove the sequence is Cauchy and that's almost all is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Over the interval $[0,1]$, the function $f(x) = \cos(x)$ is a strictly decreasing continuous function mapping $[0,1]$ into itself. So $f\circ f$ is strictly increasing there. If one pick
$a_1 = \frac{\pi}{4} \in [0,1]$ and generate a sequence by iteration $a_n = f(a_{n-1})$,
it is not hard to check

$$a_2 < a_3 < a_1$$

Since $f$ is strictly decreasing, $a_2 < a_3 < a_1 \implies a_3 > a_4 > a_2$ and hence

$$a_2 < a_4 < a_3 < a_1$$

Since $f \circ f$ is strictly increasing, this implies the even sub-sequence $a_{2n}$ is strictly increasing and the odd sub-sequence $a_{2n-1}$ is strictly decreasing. Since all $a_k$ belongs to $[0,1]$, the even and odd sub-sequences are both bounded monotonic sequences. As a result, following two limits exists:

$$a_{even} = \lim_{n\to\infty} a_{2n}\quad\text{ and }\quad
a_{odd} = \lim_{n\to\infty} a_{2n-1}$$
Since $f\circ f$ is continuous, both $a_{even}$ and $a_{odd}$ are fixed points for $f \circ f$. If one make a plot of $f\circ f$ over the interval $[0,1]$, one will notice $f \circ f$ has a unique fixed point in $[0,1]$. That point is also the unique fixed point of $f$. This forces
$a_{even} = a_{odd}$ and the sequence $a_n$ converges to the unique fixed point of $f$.